# Active record foreign key associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models as follows:

```
class Game << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bells
end

class Bell << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Now when I open the rails console, I type: @bell_instance.games.title (I get an uninitialized constant Bell::Game. When I type @bell_instance.game.title (I get an undefined method "game"). I really dont know whats wrong, this seems very simple.

I also tried adding the :foreign_key option but I get the same errors.

PS: Game has a :title field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class Bell < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Note `<` instead of `<<`. Same for `class Game`.  Also note that `@bell_instance` will have a `game` method, but not a `games` method (unless otherwise defined), because it only belongs to a single game.